# Google sheets script to add rows after different Data Headers

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am hoping people with better minds for scripting can help with this.

I am working on a data entry sheet and trying to help with automating some of the more annoying tasks, and repetitive tasks to keep the sheet looking nice.

I want to create a custom Menu Item and script that will do the following:

1. Extend the sheet by 8 rows
2. Group them together so the 1st of 8 rows is a new top level
3. Copy the header and calculation formula from the previous top level of rows to calculate the next trial.
4. Collapse the newly added rows.

To go from This:

[Original Sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KeZeb.png)

to this:

[One time extended sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EyAjQ.png)

Any help with the script specifically would be appreciated

Unfortunately I am not well versed in scripting.

Here is the current script, but I want it to ask for user input on where to start the new set of rows.

```
function NewTimeTrial() {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
var range = ss.getActiveRange();
var R = range.getRowIndex();

sheet.insertRowsBefore(12, 4);
{
var sht = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet()
var rng = sht.getRange(13,1,3,9)
rng.shiftRowGroupDepth(1)
var grp = sht.getRowGroup(13,1)
grp.collapse()
}}
```

And here is a quick windows [clip](https://clipchamp.com/watch/rNT8BXRCpWR) of the process I want to automate.

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot imagine your expected situation from `1. Extend the sheet by 8 rows`, `2. Group them together so the 1st of 8 rows is a new top level`, `3. Copy the header and calculation formula from the previous top level of rows to calculate the next trial.`, `4. Collapse the newly added rows.`. Can you provide your current script? And also, can I ask you about the detail of the current issue of your script and your goal?

Comment: Thank you for repling. In this case, in order to test the script, can you provide the sample Spreadsheet?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Can you please share a sample spreadsheet containing the format with the formulas you are using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function NewTimeTrial() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var range = ss.getActiveRange();

  var header = sheet.getRange("C3:G3") //Header to be copied 
  
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  var startRow = parseInt(ui.prompt("Please enter Row number").getResponseText()); //user input

  var dest = sheet.getRange(startRow, 3, 1, 5) //destination of new header

  sheet.insertRowsBefore(startRow, 8);

  {
    var rng = sheet.getRange(startRow + 1, 1, 7, 9)
    rng.shiftRowGroupDepth(1)
    var grp = sheet.getRowGroup(startRow + 1, 1)
    grp.collapse()
  }
  header.copyTo(dest) //copy the header to the 1st row of the new created rows
}
```

The code above will:

- Ask the user to input the row number

  - Note: please make sure to leave a blank row and input this as a row number so that the groupings will not be messed up
- It will copy/preserve calculations
- will extend sheet by 8 rows (including header)

**RESULT:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This answer assumes that the time Trial information is inserted immediately below the last trial trial.

- Create a Named Range containing the minimum headings and formula.
- Use `getLastRow()` to position the destination Range and the Activation Range

---

```
function NewTimeTrial() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1")
  var theNamedRange = ss.getRangeByName("TimeTrialProForma")

  var lr = sheet.getLastRow()
  // Logger.log("DEBUG: Last row = "+lr)

  var destinationRange = sheet.getRange(+lr+1,3)
  theNamedRange.copyTo(destinationRange);

  //Logger.log("DEBUG: Activation Range:"+sheet.getRange(+lr+3,3, 7).getA1Notation())
  sheet.getRange(+lr+3,3,7).activate().shiftRowGroupDepth(1);
}
```

---

**SAMPLE - BEFORE**

[image: before]

**SAMPLE - AFTER**

[image: after]

---

**Sample - Named Range**

[image: named range]